# How to search string for (one of) 4 different chars and proceed depending on result?

Tags: javascript, string, function, search, logic

I want to search a string for 4 different chars, and then proceed to work with the first one to be found.

tried using .lastIndexOf with .search

input has to be a string.
output needs to be the one of the 4 constant different chars which occurs last.

for example:
input string = "We can do it"
Function looks for chars "w", "e", "n","i"
wanted return = i

Comment: Show your code and what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: i dont have a solution

Comment: "I tried using lastIndexOf " Well what did you try? What is the inputs? What is the output? The question needs more details.

Comment: input has to be a string.
output needs to be the one of the 4 constant different chars which occurs last.

Comment: Give examples in your question. (More details = answers)

Comment: i wrote it more clearly... but i dont have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood you correctly but look at this.

```
const a = "my example string";
console.log(lastCharOccurrence(a));

function lastCharOccurrence(text) {
  const chars = ["a", "m", "s", "r"];
  let last;
  for (const char of text) {
    if(chars.includes(char)) {
      last = char;
    }
  }
  return last;
}
```

This has no check if no char was found, so make sure you add one if you need it.